# Dealing with express.raw for 2 different apis in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, hubspot-api

I am building an app on an a marketplace in which I receive webhooks from the app and then make api calls to perform certain actions.

I am using the **Hubspot API** for most functions and the **Stripe API** to collect payment and verify payment status. The entire code is written in Node JS and I am running the **express** node js library to listen to endpoints and deal with requests.

This is the setup of my express

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.raw({type: "application/json"})
app.use(express.json())
```

I am using `express.raw` because of the stripe API which requires the raw request to be called into some kind of Buffer.

Now this is the call for an example endpoint for a non-Stripe call, such as getting account settings for Hubspot

```
app.post('/account-fetch', (req, res) => {
  
  const portalId = req.body.portalId
  console.log(portalId)

  setup.retrieveKey(portalId, "hubname")
    .then((acc) => {
      console.log(acc)
      const component = {
        "response": {
          "accounts": [{
            "accountId": '"' + portalId + '"',
            "accountName": acc
          }]
        }
      }
      console.log(component)
      res.status(200).send(component)
    })

    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err)
      res.status(400).send(err)
    })

})
```

Now the issue is that while stripe needs it to have that express.raw call, it messes up everything else, because the Buffer is encoded and it just comes out as numbers.

I've also tried on the stripe endpoint:

```
app.post('/stripe/:type', express.raw({type: "application/json }),(req, res) => {
//rest of my code
})
```

or not calling it at all, still no cigar. All I get is a **StripeSignatureVerificationError** because it can't read the signature on the payload properly.

I've tried placing that line just before the stripe endpoint, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to either to convert the Buffer back into what it would be if I didn't do the express.raw call or a way to just make that call isolated for one endpoint?

Comment: StripeSignatureVerificationError is a webhook error. Are you sure you want to build a Stripe webhook endpoint? Since you said you want to "collect payment and verify payment status", it should be a separated endpoint with webhook.

Comment: @orakaro it is a separate endpoint. That error is happening because it can't parse the payload properly so it can't match the signature to the payload. This is because Stripe requires express.raw( {type: "application/json" }) but this messes up other endpoints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer to this. It was to use **Routers**

Essentially I did this:

```
const stripeApp = express.Router()
stripeApp.use(express.raw({type:"*/*"}))
app.use('/stripe',stripeApp)
```

and then for the endPoint:

```
stripeApp.post('/:type', express.raw({type: "application/json"}),(req, res) => {

//my code here

})
```

Both Hubspot and Stripe APIs started working.